# Instagram Third Party api

Tags: java, android, api, instagram

Actually i wanted to make a clone of instagram and show user feed in another way and change the language of app for my own country , but there are several problems with standard instagram api 
1.you cannot have user feed
2.you should become live to have user data

i guess some of apps use another api which is based on web version and i think this api fetch data from instagram webVersion or maybe official app,
i searched for a private api and i didn't found something suitable for my Task
i hope you guys could help me to find another instagram api for my job
it's better to be based on java or android

Thanks

Comment: Any progress ? please let us know.

Comment: i found something , but not very helpful , there is a php private api for instagram , it can almost do anything that instagram app can do , but working and coding with this api is a little bit hard , you can find this api here: [instagram private api](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

Comment: Please share us any progress. Thank you. Oh and you can also add those progress as an update in your question, In that way people will easily know what you have done.